# Testing a function that loads an RDS file in R

Tags: r, testing, testthat

I was wondering how you would go to test a function with testthat that loads inst/extdata rds files to do computation on ?

```
my_function = function() {

  file = paste(find.package("xyz"), "/extdata/my_file.rds", sep = "")

  if (!file.exists(file)) {
    return(stop("File could not be found."))
  }

  population = readRDS(file)

  ... and then some computation
}
```

When I do a test like this...

```
test_that("my function can read file", {
  expect_equal(my_function(), "xyz")
})
```

I get this error...

```
Error (test-xyz.R:63:3): my function can read file
Error: File could not be found.
```

Thanks for your inputs !

Comment: I'm not sure (haven't done it myself), but have you tried `system.file()` as Hadley describes here: https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#data-extdata?

Comment: extdata/ will not be where the files live once the package is built to a binary, that is just where you have to put them when writing the package. use system.file to reference them as above

Comment: Thanks guys! I was using my own fix to find the file and there was a better solution :) Works like a charm.